# How to execute one query against many databases differ in port psycopg2?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I want to query 70 databases, where login details are the same, databases differ in port (from 1 to 70).

How can I do this in python? Is it best to use the csv file for the database connection data, or use the sections in the databases file?
Maybe I can loop and make a query call sequentially just changing the port?

```
try:
    # Connect to an existing database
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="same",
                                  password="same",
                                  host="same",
                                  port="1-70",
                                  database="same")

    # Create a cursor to perform database operations
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Print PostgreSQL details
    print("PostgreSQL server information")
    print(connection.get_dsn_parameters(), "\n")
    # prepare params to query
    params = (245741049, 24780518091)
    # save results to file
    with open("randomfile.txt", "a") as o:
        for param in params:
            cursor.execute("query (%s,68,1657266483,40514);", [param])
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            addText = row, ';', param
            print(addText, file=o)
        o.close()
except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

if this code can be improved, thank you for your advice.

Comment: For each database, you need to establish a new connection using a loop in case just the port is changing.

Comment: Why 70 different databases instead of 70 schemas in one database?